# Python - Speed up generation of permutations of a list (and process of checking if permuations in Dict)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, permutation, python-itertools

I need a faster way to generate all permutations of a list, then check if each one is in a dictionary.

```
        for x in range (max_combo_len, 0, -1):
            possible_combos = []
            permutations = list(itertools.permutations(bag,x))
            for item in permutations:
                possible_combos.append(" ".join(item))
            #then check to see if each possible combo is in a specific Dict
```

If it helps, the lists are all going to be lists of strings. ['such as', 'this', 'one']

My solution works, but it's very slow. It could be that I need to stop using Python, but I thought I'd run it by you experts first!

Best,
Gary

Comment: How large of a number are we talking for `max_combo_len` and the length of `bag`? Also, if you gave us an idea of what this was for in a larger context, we might be able to provide more help.

Comment: for one thing, there's no need to turn `permutations` into a list if you are going to iterate over it with a for loop anyways.

Comment: Thanks. Max_combo_len won't go above 4 or 5. The length of bag is the length of a standard sentence. Bag is essentially a list of words ['such', 'as', 'this', 'one'], where I want to create all possible combinations of that list.

Comment: what do you mean by specific dict? one dict for each size or one dict total?

Comment: The suggestions so far may help, but they're not going to change the complexity; if it's far too slow that's probably not what you're looking for.  Please include code to generate a realistic amount of actual test data, a self-contained benchmarkable function using it, and benchmarks on your system to show what performance you're seeing and how much you'd like to improve it.

Comment: Glenn makes good points. If you specified what you are trying to do (probably in a new question) then there might be a _way_ better algorithm then brute forcing permutations. That said, I expect my posted code to outperform OP's posted code by a factor of about four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it very well without better input cases, but here are a few improvements:

```
for x in xrange(max_combo_len, 0, -1):
    possible_combos = (" ".join(item) for item in itertools.permutations(bag,x))
    #then check to see if each possible combo is in a specific Dict
    combos =  (c for c in possible_combos if c in specific_dict)
```

First, assuming you're using Python 2.x, `xrange` will help by not constructing an explicit list, but rather just yielding each `x` as you need it.

More importantly, you can throw the main effort into generator expressions and have it yield values on demand.

Answer (score 5):

A very basic optimization:

```
permutations = list(itertools.permutations(bag,x))
for item in permutations:
```

can become...

```
for item in itertools.permutations(bag,x):
```

Comment: i.e., you don't need to convert it to a list first.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for x in xrange(max_combo_len, 0, -1):
        for item in itertools.permutations(bag,x):
            combo = " ".join(item)
            if combo in specificDict:
                yield combo
```

This way you don't have any large (and getting larger) lists, you just yield the passing comobs out of the function.

Answer (score 1):

you can get rid of the many usesless (thrown away) join operations, if you prepare your special dict: just split the values or the keys, depending what you compare. This assumes of course that the dict is smaller than the number of all combos.

If you need the join, you have to slightly alter this. I *think* without you being more descriptive the problem isn't any better optimizable than this. And it's not gonna be much faster just by using another language.

```
(filtered_combo for filtered_combo in      
        itertools.chain.from_iterable(
                combo for combo in (itertools.permutations(bag, x) 
                        for x in xrange(max_combo_len, 0, -1)))
        if filtered_combo in special_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
sentences = ['such as', 'this', 'ten eggs', 'one book', 'six eggs']
bag_of_words = set(['such', 'one','ten','book','eggs'])

possible = [sentence
            for sentence in sentences
            if all(word in bag_of_words for word in sentence.split())
            ]

print 'Possible to produce from bag words are:\n\t%s' % '\n\t'.join(possible)
```

Comment: OP looked like wanting to check if combination of words is possible to produce from dictionary of words, so I thought to 'think out of box', reverse of what he seems to be trying. That takes out the exponential (factorial?) complexity of program.